# Генерация заготовок для экземпляра класса

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Есть Visual Studio 2017 и последний Resharper.

Есть какой-нибудь класс с десятком полей типа:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Inn { get; set; }

    public string Kpp { get; set; }

    public int  YetAnotherParam { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

И нужно бывает быстро что-то проверить, для чего открываешь проект с юнит-тестами и тоскливо начинаешь набирать:

```
var request = new MyRequest
{
    ID = 1,
    Inn = "",
    Kpp = ...
```

А нельзя ли чтобы не отвлекаться на эту портянку полей -- просто нажать какой-то решарперный или студийный хоткей на классе и получить заготовку, в которой уже можно сразу подставлять более реальные параметры.

Есть ли какие-то способы облегчить себе жизнь или только вручную?

Comment: Кодогенерация, например?

Comment: [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)?

Comment: Сниппеты? Это голая студия умеет.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем нам решарпер? Мыжпрограммисты! Давайте сваяем кодогенерацию.

Вот вспомогательный класс:

```
class InitializerGenerator
{
    public static string Generate<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var className = type.Name;
        var varName = char.ToLowerInvariant(className[0]) + className.Substring(1);
        var result = $"var {varName} = {GenerateTypeLiteral(type, 0)};";

        // Requires STA thread
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(
            result,
            System.Windows.TextDataFormat.UnicodeText); // PresentationCore.dll (WPF)
        // Requires STA thread
        //System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(
        //    result,
        //    System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.UnicodeText); // System.Windows.Forms.dll

        return result;
    }

    static Dictionary<Type, string> specialLiterals = new Dictionary<Type, string>()
    {
        [typeof(char)] = @"'\0'",
        [typeof(float)] = "0.0f",
        [typeof(double)] = "0.0",
        [typeof(bool)] = "false",
        [typeof(decimal)] = "0",
        [typeof(string)] = "\"\"",
    };

    const int indentSize = 4;
    static string GenerateTypeLiteral(Type type, int indentLevel)
    {
        if (specialLiterals.TryGetValue(type, out var s))
            return s;
        if (type.IsPointer)
            return "null";
        if (type.IsPrimitive)
            return "0";

        var propertyIndent = new string(' ', (indentLevel + 1) * indentSize);

        var propertytLines = new List<string>();
        foreach (var p in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (!p.CanWrite)
                continue;
            var propertyType = p.PropertyType;
            var value = GenerateTypeLiteral(propertyType, indentLevel + 1);

            propertytLines.Add($"{propertyIndent}{p.Name} = {value}");
        }

        var className = type.Name;
        var constructor = $"new {className}()";

        if (propertytLines.Count == 0)
            return constructor;

        var indent = new string(' ', indentLevel * indentSize);
        var rb = new StringBuilder();
        rb.AppendLine(constructor);
        rb.AppendLine($"{indent}{{");
        rb.AppendLine(string.Join($",{Environment.NewLine}", propertytLines));
        rb.Append($"{indent}}}");
        return rb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Его можно положить в дальний угол проекта, и при необходимости вызвать с нужными параметрами. Он даже, если хотите, поместит сгенерированный код в буфер обмена (очень удобно, кстати).

Пользоваться так:

(Определения классов)

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Inn { get; set; }
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
    public string Kpp { get; set; }
    public int YetAnotherParam { get; set; }
    public Inner2 Inner2 { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Inner2
{
    public int ID { get; }
}
```

(Код)

```
InitializerGenerator.Generate<MyRequest>();
```

Результат:

```
var myRequest = new MyRequest()
{
    ID = 0,
    Inn = "",
    Inner = new Inner()
    {
        ID = 0
    },
    Kpp = "",
    YetAnotherParam = 0,
    Inner2 = new Inner2()
};
```

Недостатки: не генерирует параметры конструктора, исходит из существования конструктора по умолчанию (так что нужный конструктор придётся вызывать вручную). Можно было бы добавить и это, но непонятно, что делать в случае наличия нескольких конструкторов.

Comment: почему бы T4 для этого не использовать?

Comment: @tym32167: Вполне можно, да.

Comment: @tym32167 есть желание написать свою версию ответа? мне кажется, что задачу действительно разными способами решить и я вполне готов отметить конкурсными баллами другие варианты.

Comment: @AK не, я пас :)