# Расширенный автокомплит в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пишу код в Visual Studio - одна из последних

Напрягает много одних и тех же действий, можно ли это как то вылечить ?

Например вызываю метод:

`private string Proverka(string text1, string text2,string text3)`

Для того что бы к нему обратиться, приходится написать часть названия метода:

`pr`

в подсказке кликнув на него, получится полное название

`Proverka`

затем нажав открывающуюся скобку , появляются обе - удобно

`Proverka()`

А вот возможно ли одним нажатием что бы получалось вот так ?

```
Proverka("","","");
```

Т.е. что то на подобии кода вызываешь цикл `for` , достаточно написать `fo` нажать 2 раза `tab` и готово

Comment: Можно решарпер поставить.

Comment: спрашивал [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757967/213987), направление движения - кодогенерация. В вашем случае же вы будете указывать реальные значения (и больше двух-трёх параметров в функцию моветон передавать, делают отдельный класс для параметров) либо все три параметра вы могли указать как параметры по умолчанию и не передавать их вовсе.

Comment: Можно сниппет написать, но, имхо, это не тот случай когда он нужен. Я вот проблем не вижу поставить пару запятых. А вставлять пары кавычек в качестве параметров - вообще вредно: либо вы пишете плохой код, либо вам просто придется удалять эти кавычки. Вообще достаточно написать пару начальных символов метода, затем стрелками вверх-вниз выбрать правильный метод из выпадающего списка и нажать пробел или сразу открывающую скобку.

Comment: Вводим `Pr`, далее сразу жмём открывающую скобку. Не нужно кликов мышкой.

Comment: Пишем `Proverka("","","");`, выделяем, копируем в буфер обмена (Ctrl+C). Далее жмём Ctrl+V столько раз, сколько нужно.

Comment: `Proverka("","","");`. А смысл проверять константные выражения? Все равно в дальнейшей разработке будут использоваться строковые переменные. Такая кодогенерация бесполезна.